# How to implement "Tumblr" menu

Tags: android, menu, tumblr

Hi I am new in mobile app development. I found the menu of the app "Tumblr" very interesting. But I did not get any code for that kind of menu. All I have got is few codes for satellite menu in android. Please help me if some one knows how to create such kind of menu.

Thanks in advance.

[image]